# Should a semicolon precede an adverb that does not separate two independent clauses?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons

The sentence I wrote is as follows:

> The idea behind this technique was that the human eye could not differentiate between the individual colors of each point, thereby causing the eye to blend the colors together to form a more complete image.

My professor said that the "thereby" in that sentence should have a semicolon behind it and a comma in front, but as far as I know, a semicolon separates two independent clauses. I don't think "causing the eye to blend colors together ..." is a complete sentence, but she said it should be written as ";thereby,". Is she correct?

Answer (score 2):

If I had to use the exact words that you used, I would punctuate the sentence exactly as you have: with a comma before *thereby* and no punctuation immediately after it.

I suspect, however, that the professor's suggested alteration may have been motivated by dissatisfaction with the wording of the sentence, and by the erroneous idea that a change in punctuation would take care of the sentence's perceived shortcomings.

To me, the awkwardness of the wording is due primarily to its association of *thereby* (which means essentially "in this way" or "by this means") not with an action but with a negative capability (the inability of the human eye to differentiate between the individual colors of each point). To avoid that awkward association of ideas, I would remove *thereby* and reword the sentence as follows:

> The idea behind this technique was that, because the human eye could not differentiate between the individual colors of each point, the eye would blend the colors together to form a more complete image.

The comma between *that* and *because* is optional (depending on the approach you take toward punctuation); the comma between *point* and *the* is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

[I think she's referring to rule #2, or #3 further down](http://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Semicolons.html) in her suggestion, but I also think you are right in that it is not a complete thought after the thereby.  You could rephrase it, using her suggestion, to something such as:

; thereby, the eye blends the colors together to form a more complete image.

Comment: The semicolon and comma make sense if you rephrase it like that, but I'm more interested in the correct punctuation usage for the sentence as it is. I suppose I could change it, but I rather like the original way I wrote it. If the thereby causes confusion, I could probably just remove it and keep it as "... each point, causing the eye ..." Do you think that would sound better?

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion was made due to the transition in the ideas presented. Your usage of punctuation is applicable for coordinators. There is a thin line and subjective view towards this difference in punctuation because coordinators and transitions join independent clauses. The use of punctuation depends on the connectors, and the usage of connectors depend on the text.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, which is whether a semicolon should....

Answer (score -1):

Your professor probably made the suggestion because either a semicolon or "and" is needed to join the clauses and a comma follows "thereby" just as it would follow an adverb that introduces a clause.

Comment: Hi O.E.M, welcome to English Language & Usage. This site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: opinions *as answers* are strongly discouraged, with preference given instead to detailed answers quoting and/or linking to a source (eg a dictionary definition). For help writing a good answer, see [Answer]. For more information about how EL&U works, please take the **[Tour]**. :-)